# Show that an integral function is a Borel function

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, outer-measure, borel-measures

I've been trying to prove that the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal function is a Borel Function for a while now (and was hoping to get some help) and have been stuck on the final step for a while, which is to show that, fixing $r>0$ and letting $(X,d)$ be a metric space then

$$I(x) =  \int_{B_r(x)} |f| d\mu$$ is a Borel function. Where $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and $\mu$ is a outer Borel measure (which means Borel sets are $\mu$ measurable) with the property that $\mu(B_r(x)) < \infty$ for all $r$ and $x$.

I've boiled the problem down to showing that the above holds if one can show that the function $\mu(B_r(x)\cap A)$ is a Borel function. Where $A$ is any arbitrary $\mu$-measurable set.

I have tried to come up with counter examples just in case but any weird measure that I come up with it tends to break one of the two conditions imposed on $\mu$.

$\underline{EDIT}$
Here are some definitions that may not be standard and hence have added them to clear things up. (Also in the course I am doing we call outer measures, measures so this might explain the weird naming I the following definitions)

A set $A \subset X$ is said to be $\mu$ measurable if $\forall E \subset X$ the
$$\mu(E) = \mu(E\cap A) +\mu(E\setminus A)$$

$\mu$ is said to be Borel if every Borel set is $\mu$ measurable. e.g. $\delta _0$ is Borel when $X=\mathbb{R}$ but also the Vitali set is $\delta _0$ measuable but not a Borel set

A function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be $\mu$ Borel if for all $a \in \mathbb{R}, f^{-1}((a,\infty)$ is a Borel set.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that $\mu$ is the measure induced by an outer measure on the Borel sets, then we can take simple functions $s_n\uparrow |f|$ and apply the Monotone or Dominated Convergence Theorem: if we define $I_n$ by

$I_n(x):=\int_X s_n(x) \chi_{B_r}(x)d\mu$ then the $I_n$ are  $\mu-$measurable and satisfy

$\lim I_n(x)=\int_X \lim s_n(x) \chi_{B_r}(x)d\mu=\int_X|f(x)|\chi_{B_r}(x)d\mu =\int _{B_r(x)}|f(x)|d\mu=I(x)$

so $I$ is measurable being the limit of $\mu-$ measurable functions.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do I am struggling to show that the simple functions are indeed Borel functions. As I do not know that the only $\mu$ measurable sets are Borel sets and hence $I_n^-1((a,\infty))$ well be measurable but not necessarily a Borel set. I will edit the question to add more details and definitions.

Comment: If $\mu^*$ induces a measure $\mu$ on the Borel sets, and if $f\in L^1(\mu)$ then by $definition$ there are such $\mu-$ measurable $s_n$. Unless I am not understanding your question. Are you confusing the outer measure with the  measure it induces?

Comment: I've added an edit which will hopefully clear things up I now see the definitions I was given are not standard sorry